# How do I "merge" two YAML text files?

Tags: git, merge, yaml, pyyaml

use meld / xxdiff / or something else?

say if I have two yaml files, how can I merge them automatically? each of them has a few hundred lines.  the common part is abc:

```
abc:
  x:
    0: null
  y:
    1: null

def:
  x:
    0: string

...
```

and

```
abc:
  u: null
  v: null
  w: null

def:
  u: 
    0: null
  v: null
  w: null
...
```

desired result:

```
abc:
  x:
    0: null
  y:
    1: null
  u: null
  v: null
  w: null

def:
  x:
    0: string
  u: 
    0: null
  v: null
  w: null
```

can this be done with any diff/merge tools?

edit: fixed typo in desired result

Comment: Isn't `def` a common part, too? Do you really want to merge `abc` but have different entries for `def`?

Comment: Since your output is [no longer valid YAML](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2764652), can you enlighten us what you are going to do with it? On what basis would the `abc` key's values be merged and the `def` key's value not? First position? The actual name? What would happen if `abc` was after `def` in the second file? Are your input files really such simplistic subset of YAML, e.g no comments between mapping entries, no anchors?

Comment: ah sorry just typo. I'll edit my question. I want to end result to be valid yaml, but with two files combined. @Anthon yes my input files are as simple as above and there are no comment.

Comment: I've voted to close this question as off-topic because it's a recommendation for a tool rather than a request for assistance with your code. That said, [this](https://github.com/otrosien/yaml-merge) or [this](https://github.com/alexlafroscia/yaml-merge) might work for you.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do what you want to without parsing the files. However you can do so with a short python program:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml = YAML()
yaml.explicit_end = True
data = None

for file_name in sys.argv[1:]:
    d = yaml.load(open(file_name, 'rb'))
    if data is None:
        data = d
        continue
    for k in d:
        data[k].update(d[k])

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

this gives (assuming the appropriate input files:

```
abc:
  x:
    0:
  y:
    1:     

  u:
  v:
  w:
def:
  x:
    0: string
  u:
    0:
  v:
  w:
...
```

Please note that the extra whitespace gets lost as [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) (disclosure: I am the author of that package), only (partly) preserves whitespace if ajacent to comments. You also would need to make the `.update()` smarter, i.e. recursive, if more than top-level key merging is required.

Comment: There is currently no simple way to explicitly dump python None values back as explicit null values. It can be done however with some extra code

Comment: With my yml files it failed with: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'update'`.

Comment: The above assumes that the root level is a mapping with values that again are mappings, as in the OPs question. Post a new question, with your actual YAML files (or an excerpt) and tag the question with ruamel.yaml (then I willl be automatically notified).

Comment: Ok, it is another question. But a script which could handle any structure, making no assumptions, would be better.

Comment: @sekrett I don't think that is so easily done. If one YAML file has a mapping at the rootlevel and another has a sequence at a rootlevel, I wouldn't know how to proceed. What does merging mean if a mapping value for the same key in different YAML documents has a scalar value, then what does merging mean? Replacing, creating a sequence with both values? As long as you unambigiously define "merging" for all possible situations and have YAML documents that have the same structure (i.e. same collection type given the same path from the root) such a script could indeed be made.

Comment: That would still make restrictive assumptions, albeit less restrictive than the program in my answer. But it would also be one or two orders of magnitude more work to create.

Comment: Thanks, now I got it. To merge two yaml files a strategy is required. BTW with hiyapyco also I did not get what I need, but at least it worked without errors. Migth be useful for some simple cases.

Answer (score 1):

Another Python script, which works:

```py
import sys
import hiyapyco

merged_yaml = hiyapyco.load(sys.argv[1:], method=hiyapyco.METHOD_MERGE)
print(hiyapyco.dump(merged_yaml))
```

Save it as a file and pass file names as arguments:

```sh
python3 ./merge_yml.py first.yml second.yml > result.yml
```